# What causes Error in task 1 failed - "numbers of columns of arguments do not match" in RFE?

Tags: r, r-caret, rfe

I am trying to experiment with recursive feature selection in caret by the following command:

```
result <- rfe(x = as.matrix(data.x.train),
          y = data.y.train,
          sizes = seq(from = 100, to = 10000, length = 10),
          rfeControl = rfeControl(functions = rfFuncs,
                                  method = "cv",
                                  number = 5,
                                  rerank = TRUE,
                                  verbose = TRUE,
                                  saveDetails = TRUE,
                                  allowParallel = TRUE))
```

the `data.x.train` matrix contains:

```
> dim(data.x.train)
[1]  1563 12338
```

and `data.y.train`:

```
> length(data.y.train)
[1] 1563
```

and contains 8 levels:

```
> table(data.y.train)
data.y.train
                  A    B    C    D 
                  515  311  179  149 
                  E    F    G    H 
                  205  133  42   29
```

what setting can possibly cause:

```
  Error in { : 
  task 1 failed - "numbers of columns of arguments do not match"
```

after a few hours of running the command?

Thanks

Comment: Providing a reproducible example and the results of `sessionInfo` will help get your question answered.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the rerank = TRUE, option, worked for me facing the same problem

Comment: This did not work for me for the same issue. I was not using rerank = TRUE to begin with, and I am having the same error.